# Lookup/ Index/ Match

Tags: excel-formula

Look up criteria:

1. Policy period is different for different dealers. Each dealer has their own policy period.
2. On the basis of the date of loss, I need to find out which period does that loss fall into.

Data set:

This is the file wherein I need the period and the year to be updated

[image: Result Table1a]

Another file which has the details of the policy start and end period and which year it falls under. Policy start period is different for different OEM. On the basis of the date of loss, we need to find out which period does the date of loss fall under.

[image: Data Table]

Tried using Index, Match and Lookup function.

```
=INDEX(PeriodLookup[[#All],[OEM]:[Policy Year]],MATCH([@[OEM Name** Updated]],PeriodLookup[[#All],[OEM]],0),MATCH(Attach_C[[#All],[Date of Loss]],PeriodLookup[[#All],[Effective]],1))
```

Here is the expected result:

[image]

Comment: Can you please update your first picture to show the expected result in the `year` and `period` column which should be from your second picture. Also please post your `index+match` formula so we may find out where went wrong?

Comment: I have updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have the following **named ranges**:

- **OEM** being the `OEM` column in your `PeriodLookup` table;
- **Effective** being the `Effective` column in your `PeriodLookup` table;
- **Policy_Period** being the `Policy Period` column in your `PeriodLookup` table.

> **Approach** 1: Find `Year` within sorted data

If your data have been grouped by name and sorted by date from smallest to largest (which is important), you can use **VLOOKUP** to find the closest Effective date within a **filtered** range using **IF** function, and then use **YEAR** function to find out the year of the effective date. Here is the formula to be put in Cell `D2` to find **Year**:

```
{=IFERROR(YEAR(VLOOKUP(B2,IF(OEM=C2,Effective),1,1)),"NA")}
```

> **Approach 2**: Find `Year` within randomly ordered data

If your data is randomly ordered, you can use **AGGREGATE** function to sort the filtered **Effective** date range first, and then use **INDEX+MATCH** to return the closest match from the range. The following array formula will return `NA` if there is no match.

```
{=IFERROR(YEAR(INDEX(AGGREGATE(15,6,IF(OEM=C2,Effective),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,ROWS(OEM)))),MATCH(B2,AGGREGATE(15,6,IF(OEM=C2,Effective),ROW($A$1:INDEX($A:$A,ROWS(OEM)))),1))),"NA")}
```

Once the **Year** is known, you can use **INDEX+MATCH** to return the corresponding policy period within another **filtered** range. Here is the formula to be put in Cell `E2` to find **Period**:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Policy_Period,MATCH(D2,IF((OEM=C2),YEAR(Effective)),0)),"")}
```

> Just a reminder, all formulas used are **Array Formula** so you need to press 
>   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in the formula bar after entering the formula otherwise it will not return the correct result. Then you can drag them down to apply across board.

Screenshot for **Approach 1**

[image: Example1]

Screenshot for **Approach 2**

[image: Example2]

Let me know if you have any questions. Cheers :)

Comment: Is there any way wherein the formula is not based on sorting?

Comment: @Saagar yes there is. I have updated my answer with a second approach to find `Year` from a randomly sorted data set. As you can see it is a much longer and complicated formula as I need to sort the filtered ranged first and then find the closest match whereas my first approach just need to find the closest match from a sorted data set. Let me know if you have further query.